# Account Registeration Issue In Android Device

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-emulator, sip

Android Application :

```
Basically application has to register few credentials like username , password
```

`& domain to  Sip server -teksip on the system and get the status back as ok  or 200` `from server. When i run from Emulator android 2.3.3 application works smooth and fast result as` `registered.Even in Sip Server i get my credentials as working.`

```
I used Pjsip based sip stack in my application.
```

Environment :

```
Eclipse 3.7
android sdk
Emulator 2.3.3
teksip 3.3
```

`Issue :`
When I run application from Emulator It runs fine and gives the expected result as registering on sip server (Used System set domain as 192.168.1.2:portNo.).
But the Issue comes when i run the android device 2.3.3 where i didnt get registeration . Now i am not getting why this problem occuring where as it runs exactly as expected on emulator 2.3.3 . I hope some one could answer this ?

Comment: i have tried apjsua sample app of pjsip but it does't work for me. I have generated libraries by following their android tutorial but the sample app is not working fine.. will you please help me in creating sip client for android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try capturing the network traffic between your phone and the sip proxy (e.g. using [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) and then filtering for the SIP protocol). Maybe compare it to the traffic that the emulator generates

Also try to look at the system log where your sip proxy is installed and at the log cat of android. pjsip is logging quite some stuff.